# How to parseFloat an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using this type of array to read data.

```
var myFood = new Array();     
    function Food(aCode, aRating, aPrice, anImage, aRate, aWeight) {
    this.Image = anImage;
    this.Rating = aRating;
    this.Price = aPrice;
}
```

It is then organized in subdata groups which I put in a dropdown select

```
        myFood[i] = new Food(subdata[0], subdata[1], subdata[2]); 
      }     
        var mySelect = document.getElementById("selFood");
    for (i = 0; i < myFood.length; i++) {
        var myOption = document.createElement("option");
        myOption.text = myFood[i].Code;
        myOption.value = i;
        mySelect.add(myOption, null);
    }
```

Then I display the output

```
    function chooseFood(){
    var myIndex = document.getElementById("selFood").value;
    document.getElementById("imgFood").src = myFood[myIndex].Image;
    document.getElementById("spnRating").innerHTML = myFood[myIndex].Rate;
    document.getElementById("spnPrice").innerHTML = myFood[myIndex].Price;
```

Since the "price" data is a number (for example $20.00) how can I reduce every price index before it is displayed.  According to the theme there is a 10% off of every price.  How can ensure that every object of the array gets that discount.

Comment: Since you re using Object which is a good practice why dont you create a PriceDiscount function under this object e.x. Food.prototype.PriceDiscounted = function(){return parseFloat(this.Price) * 10 / 100;}; and then you can call as myFood[myIndex].PriceDiscounted();

Answer (score 0):

Pass the "myIndex" value in the method and multiply the price by 90/100

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement that is to use the [module pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/) on your food "class".

To reduce on every food loop the array and call the method on every index.

```js
var myFood = new Array();     
function Food(aCode, aRating, aPrice, anImage, aRate, aWeight) {  
    return {
        Image: anImage,
        Rating: aRating,
        Price: aPrice,
        
        addDiscount: function(discount) {
           this.Price = this.Price - (this.Price / 100 * discount);   
        }
    }
}

var i = 0;

myFood[i] = new Food('xxx', '1', 20); 

console.log(myFood);

myFood[i].addDiscount(10);

console.log(myFood);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one more property named DiscountPercent and then Create a function named DiscountedPrice which takes DiscountPercent and Price as parameters and returns the DiscountedPrice.

```
function DiscountedPrice(DiscountPercent,Price){
return Price*(100 - DiscountedPrice)/100;
}
```

by this you can change the individual Discount Price Later without changing the Code.